# How to fix groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method when calculating the total

Tags: grails, cassandra

I am trying to connect to Cassandra and write a query in Grails to total the amount but I am getting a missing method exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: project
>   .sampleTest.column() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [amount]
>   Possible solutions: collect(), dump(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)

Below is the query what I have written to sum the amount.

```
Select selectQuery = QueryBuilder.select().fcall("sum", column("amount")).from(tableName).allowFiltering()

Session session = cassandraTemplate.getSession();

Where selectWhere = selectQuery.where();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a column name inside of [`fcall()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Selection.html#fcall-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) you need to use the static method [`QueryBuilder.column()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#column-java.lang.String-). So when you use it in `fcall()` you need to call it like:

```
Select selectQuery = QueryBuilder.select().fcall("sum", QueryBuilder.column("amount")).from(tableName).allowFiltering()
```